# Remove Path from Conda env

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter, conda, qgis

I'm currently running Python 3.7.6 (64bit) in a few Conda envs, all of them I use to work in jupyter.
I added Jupyter outside of conda for my qgis python 3.7 (32bit) and all my conda envs now point to this kernel and refuse to work for everything except qgis.
I've worked around this by deleting the entire path and all the conda kernels launch again, which then breaks the qgis kernel.
Is there a way I can easily remove the python 3.7 paths from the conda envs so they ignore it?
Or should I just not use the python that comes with qgis and build a conda env from scratch?